# on() function in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am making dynamic buttons using jQuery. Now I want to use this buttons as any other buttons. Here is my HTML:

```
<label class='twobuttons'><div id="submit-button" >GO!</div></label>
<div id='result'></div>
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit-button').click(function(){
        $('#result').append("<label><div id='share' class='longbutton'>Share this route</div></label>");

        $('#result').append("<label><div id='goback' class='longbutton'>Create another one !</div></label>");
    });

    $('#share').on("click",function(){
        alert('hi');
    });

    $('#goback').on("click",function(){
        alert('hello');
    })
});
```

I'm specifically having trouble with the `$('#share').on(` part.

I tried the `on()` function as suggested [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/problem-for-dynamically-created-button). But it is not working. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L7mc9/) is the fiddle of my code. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: IDs must be unique.  And you need to pass a delegating selector to `on()`; see the documentation.

Comment: how are you creating the "dynamic buttons". At what point is the `.on()` declared

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't how `.on()` works, if you are dynamically creating elements, you can't bind an event handler to it, because at the point the code runs (document.ready), the element doesn't exist. So to "get around" that, you bind the event to a parent element (that exists) and then add the actual element you'll be clicking on as a parameter like this:

```
    $('body').on("click", "#share", function(){
        alert('hi');
    });

    $('body').on("click", "#goback",function(){
     alert('hello');
    })
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L7mc9/1/)

Comment: `.on()` should be used to attach event handlers regardless if dynamically created or not. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Andy I think Jack is referring to you saying `That isn't how .on() works` and suggesting you must always `bind the event to a parent element and then add the actual element you'll be clicking on as a parameter`. Because that isn't required.

Comment: @Ian That is correct.

Comment: @Ian I didn't say a dynamically created element was required, did I? :o

Comment: I got a question. Why adding '#share' in on() didnt worked ?

Comment: @Andy The way it's worded, it's what it sounds like. You seem to suggest that delegation is required when using `on()`. I'm guessing you didn't mean that, it just sounds like it. I think you meant to explain it more as it is related to dynamic elements and binding events

Comment: @user1263375 Because the way on works is it binds the event handler to the element inside the selector, `#share` in this case, but it didn't exist when document was ready (because you created it after document ready). Whereas my code binds the event handle to the body, which does exist at doc ready.

Comment: @Ian Attempted to clear it up, TL;DR: `if you are dynamically creating elements...`

Comment: @Andy Much better :) I just didn't want the OP or others to get the wrong idea. Again, you obviously know what you're talking about, it just sounded weird

Comment: Why are you binding the event handler to `'body'` if `'#result'` is already there at page load? Blindly using the catch-all element to register your event handlers will eventually come to haunt you. Btw, different Jack :)

Answer (score 5):

You should setup event delegation on `#result` instead, because by the time you're trying to setup the click handlers on `#share`, the element itself has not been added yet.

```
$('#result').on('click', '#share', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

*Try not to bind the event handler to `$(document)` by default; the closest element that will not get removed is the prime candidate.*

Alternatively, only bind the click handlers *after* you've added the new elements.

**Update**

You're appending elements with a fixed identifier at every click of your button; note that identifiers should be unique per document, so you should make sure that the action is performed at most once.

Comment: Why was this downvoted twice?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I think we have a serial downvoter.  We all seem to have been downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

The way the .on() method works changes according to how you use it. In your example the .on() method behaves similar to bind and will **only work on elements that already exist**.
Try this:

```
 $(document).on("click",'#share',function(){
              alert('hi');
          });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dgJe4/)

Comment: It looks like we may have a serial downvoter.  I was downvoted, too, with no explanation given.

Comment: Greate random downvotes @DerekHenderson

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough to use `.on()`. You have to use event delegation with an element (such as `document`) that existed before your dynamically-created elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '#share', function () {
    alert('hi');
});
```

(Based on your fiddle, you can use `#result` instead of `document`.)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7mc9/5/)

Comment: i tried. Not working. Can you post some fiddle ?

Comment: Yes, it is working, but I will update with a fiddle to prove it to you.

Comment: @user1263375, I've now updated my answer with a fiddle.

Comment: Um, why the downvote?  This is a technically correct answer.

Comment: I didn't down voted. Its just that I can only correct one answer. :)

Comment: Of course, @user1263375, and the accepted answer is a good one.  It's just that someone has downvoted every answer, including the accepted answer.

Comment: Maybe. Well i upvoted yours

Comment: @user1263375, thanks, I appreciate it. And for the record, I wasn't accusing you of downvoting me. Three of us complained, and looking at the reputation changes for every user who posted an answer you can see that each of us was downvoted by someone. Not that it matters that much. ;)